# Dict comprehension merge all values in list of dicts with same date

Tags: python

I want to add the value of all dicts with the same year. I have been trying `defaultdict` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) for several hours but cant find any examples that simply adds to a total.

I have a list of dicts that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "year": 2020,
        "value": 6500.0
    },
    {
        "year": 2020,
        "value": 40500.0
    },
    {
        "year": 2019,
        "value": 6500.0
    },
    {
        "year": 2019,
        "value": 20000.0
    }
]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[
    {
        "year": 2020,
        "value": 47000.0
    }
    {
        "year": 2019,
        "value": 26500.0
    }
]
```

I tried a ton of variation of `defaultdict`, like:

```
all_won_deals = //contains dict above
concenated = collections.defaultdict(set)
for k, v in all_won_deals:
    concenated[k].add(v)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use `itertools.groupby`.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

get_year = itemgetter('year')  # For sorting and grouping
get_value = itemgetter('value')  # For aggregating

result = [{'year': y, 
           'value': sum(map(get_value, ds))
          } 
          for y, ds in groupby(sorted(all_won_deals, key=get_year), get_year)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your `concatenated` defaultdict (though you'll want a `defaultdict(list)` to keep duplicates!), run a sum over it as a list comprehension:

```
sums = [{"year": key, "value": sum(values)} for (key, values) in concatenated.items()]
```